# What is typical phrases to say to your friend when you're surprised by him/her?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, idioms, phrases

The situation is;

One of your friends/colleagues suddenly appears from your behind and says "Boo!" You are so surprised.

What is typical words to say to him/her when you want him/her to stop it but want to deliver the words friendly?

I come up with "You startled me!" and "Don't scare me!" Could you tell me alternative  words for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this often. They tell me

> 1. Don't do that!
> 2. Stop it!
> 3. Quit it!

among other things.
Each is usually preceded by

> Oh my god

I think it depends on *how* you say it, not so much *what* you say. If you say it in a nice, playful manner, then that is how it will come off. If you say it sternly then that is how it will come off.

Answer (score 1):

You could call him/her *cheeky*. [The Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cheeky) defines it as, 'slightly rude or showing no respect, but often in a funny way.'

You could say something like:

> Oi, cheeky, don't scare me.

You could also say the words in a friendly or playful way.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell your friend

> Please don't do that, you really scared me.
>   Do you want to give me a heart attack?
>   Don't scare me like that!

However, if you do have the presence of mind and don't look too startled, you can just say "Boo!" back to your friend in a calm tone of voice, it will probably annoy your friend to no end.